# Absolute URLs not working with Virtual Directories?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url, iis

I created several virtual directors and I want to be able to get the url from the current http request.

**For example:**

`http://www.site.com/app_1/default.aspx   ===>   http://www.site.com/app_1/`

`http://www.site.com/app_2/default.aspx   ===>   http://www.site.com/app_2/`

....

`http://www.site.com/app_n/default.aspx   ===>   http://www.site.com/app_n/`

**My code:**

```
    string urlApp = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();
    urlApp = urlApp.Substring(0, urlApp.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

and I tried

```
    string urlApp = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + "/";
```

In localhost works great: `http://localhost:2468/test.aspx` result `http://localhost:2468/`

, but when access via virtual directory `http://myhost/app_1/test.aspx` result `http://myhost/`

how can i get `http://myhost/app_1/`?

Comment: Have you tried seeing what `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToString();` actually returns? Maybe it is just returning `http://myhost/app_1/`, and then your substring is removing the app_1 part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath
```

is what you need to get the route to your virtual directory. Append it to the URL you've already gotten and you're onto a winner. Something like

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath
```

Should work, but look out for trailing slashes.

Comment: @dumitru Please Up Vote the answers as well